# I am interested in getting the user's email address even when the user refuses it during facebook login process

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I am interested in getting the user's email address even when the user refuses it during facebook login process. When the user refuses to give 'email permission' during facebook login, then in firebase his email is '---'. Is it possible to make 'email' scope required?

Answer (score 1):

If you can access to source code and find where is refusing code, you probably can modding this to your needs. But you have a big probability to get an obfuscated code (unreadable by a human)

Answer (score 0):

Right after login, you can check for the currently authorized permissions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/permissions/

If the email permission is not included, ask for it again. Keep in mind that not everyone has an email, it is not required for Facebook.